# What are the advantages and disadvantages of XML Schema over Editor tool?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

We are using DTD and entity in our project. it is accessed by some third party editor tool for processing and i analyze xml schema as an alternative for editor tool and i get collect advantages and disadvantages of the same.

Could professionals share me valuable points regarding this?

Comment: So the question is about the availability, maturity and features of GUI/IDE/Editor support for XML Schema vs DTD?

Answer (score 0):

I am using notepad++ , eclipse to edit my xsd file , some plugins in notepad++ is . eclipse is also supporting visual xsd editing , which is serving my purpsoe . i think recent editors are matured enough to do our task smoothly regardsing to DTD.